# Test Results window in VS2008 not showing results

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have an existing solution that has been working for a long time, containing around 600 tests in a couple of test projects.  I recently moved to a new PC - it's Win7-x64, and I installed a fresh copy of VS2008.  When I first opened the solution on the new machine, the Test List Editor was completely empty.  Trying to create a new test list caused the editor to refresh, and now it shows my test lists, but they're acting funny.

I can select tests in the lists, and run them, but the results window doesn't usually update automatically to show the results of the latest test.  It has done this when running a single test a couple of times, but even that is not consistent.  The only way I can view the results is by manually going to the Test Runs window and connecting to individual test runs.  When I do that, the results show up in the results list, but I can't check them to re-run the failed tests - the check boxes are all disabled.

I guess I should describe the way it used to work, in case that was unusual - I used to select some tests from the Test Lists window, tell it to run them, and the results window would clear itself, and then display the results from the current run.  I could then check any tests that I wanted to re-run, and use the run/debug button in the results window to do so.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, after rebooting my machine, the problem mysteriously vanished.